# Packing enums using the MSVC++ compiler

Tags: c++, enums, packing

With GCC, I could do packing of enums using **attribute**((**packed**)), but it seems the closest thing in MSVC, #pragma pack, does not work on enums.  Does anyone know of a way to pack enums into 1 byte instead of the usual integer size?

Comment: given that using it (if it existed) will lead to non portable code, why would you need to use that anyway?

Comment: Because sometimes portability is irrelevant and compatibility with another system is needed. Years ago I wanted this when communicating via shared RAM to a 68K board (whose compiler supported specifying the size of an enum).

Comment: @Steve Fallows In that case I would prefer a (set of) functions to convert from the C enum to and from the external format. that is safer (as there may be endian conversions necessary (not in this case, but generally) and portable.

Answer (score 3):

This is MSVC specific:

```
// instances of this enum are packed into 1 unsigned char
// warning C4480: nonstandard extension used
enum foo : unsigned char { first, second, last }; 
assert(sizeof(foo) == sizeof(unsigned char));

// instances of this enum have the common size of 1 int
enum bar { alpha, beta, gamma };
assert(sizeof(bar) == sizeof(int));
```

For reference see here:
[MSDN -> enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: I think that's C#.  I've never seen such syntax in C++.  If it works though, that's really cool.  I'll refrain from downvoting because I'm unsure.

Comment: maybe MSVC already implements c++ 0x, but then it should be "class enum" if I am not mistaken

Comment: No, it's not C++/CLI or C#. It's a MS extension to plain C++, similar to what gcc does with attribute((packed)).

Comment: From the link explaining the warning: "An extension to the language under /clr was used without /clr. You can disable C4480".

It's a c++/cli extension that you can use in native c++.

Comment: @rmeador: read the answer -- it is MSVC specific. That means you won't find it in other compilers.